# Bean properties are shared across different sessions

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

I am using JSF Mojarra 2.1.13, PrimeFaces 3.5 and Spring 3.2.3 for my application. For DI I am using Spring approach (not CDI). I am following the tutorial on PrimeFaces demos with the collector: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/collector.jsf

Everything is working fine, I can add my values to the list, get them, etc.. The problem is that for e.g. if I open two browsers and adding some values into the list, then in another browser I am adding a few values as well, and if I refresh browsers I am seeing the all the values which has been entered in both browsers. So if I enter two values in one browser two in the other, after refreshing them I am seeing four values in both browsers. I want my values to not be shared across different sessions.

My bean looks like this:

```
@Component
@ManagedBean
public class ClientBean extends BaseBean {

    private Client client = new Client();

    private List<Client> clients = new LinkedList<>();

    public String reInit() {
        client = new Client();
        return null;
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public List<Client> getClients() {
        return clients;
    }

    public void setClients(List<Client> clients) {
        this.clients = clients;
    }
}
```

I know that I am creating global variables:

```
private Client client = new Client();    
private List<Client> clients = new LinkedList<>();
```

But this is showed in tutorial. So how can I handle this situation to make collector work so that those variables won't be shared across different sessions?

**EDIT**
I have tried to annotate my bean with: `@RequestScoped` or `@SessionScoped` - didn't work. The same problem remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really sure why you configured the `@ManagedBean` as a `@Component` to begin with. This problem is because Spring handles a single instance of `@Component` across your application (or at least that's how it looks from your explanation). Remove it and use `@ViewScoped` in your managed bean to make this work as expected. Note that if you use Spring to manage your JSF managed beans, then you have to add this configuration in your *faces-config.xml* (from [mkyong tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/)):

```xml
<application>
    <el-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>
```

But doing this you will loss the power of `@ViewScoped` managed beans. To solve this error, you have to implement the `@ViewScoped` in Spring. There are plenty examples on the net about this, and looks that the most popular is from [Cagatay's](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/)

More info about JSF managed bean scopes: [Communication in JSF 2: Managed bean scopes](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes)

Comment: That's great answers. I am just starting to get JSF working with Spring. I didn't know that I can have a view scope with Spring. The reason I am using ManagedBean with Component is that the Component serves Spring DI purpose and from ManagedBean I can display values in the view. I wouldn't be able to use it in JSF tags if it wouldn't be annotated with ManagedBean. But yeah, this is now clear. Thanks very much!